# Не работает код css в связке с jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Задача заключается в том, чтобы при наведении курсора мыши картинка смещалась на заданное количество px, но никак не хочет срабатывать! Прошу помощи, кто с таким сталкивался?

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".logo").mouseover(function(event) {
    $(".logo").css(
      {"background-position":"0px 0px",
      "transition-duration":"5s",
      "animation":"animatedBackground"
    });
    }
  )

  })
```

```css
@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0px 0px; }

  to {
    background-position: 500px 0px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0px 0px; }

  to {
    background-position: 500px 0px; }
}

.logo {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT64cprQO-leFSi_6p8BcHqzU1vJnh4afu6dcegcdnG5JCw4mo7");
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/usegsxL8/4/

Answer (score 2):

```css
@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0px 0px; }

  to {
    background-position: 500px 0px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0px 0px; }

  to {
    background-position: 500px 0px; }
}

.logo {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT64cprQO-leFSi_6p8BcHqzU1vJnh4afu6dcegcdnG5JCw4mo7");
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.logo:hover{
  background-position:0px 0px;
  transition-duration:5s;
  animation-name:animatedBackground;
  animation-duration:2s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>animashka</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="logo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

```css
@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 500px 0px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 500px 0px;
  }
}

.logo {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT64cprQO-leFSi_6p8BcHqzU1vJnh4afu6dcegcdnG5JCw4mo7");
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.logo:hover {
  animation-name: animatedBackground;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo"></div>
```